# SSAS where are olap cubes stored

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, olap

Getting started on creating data cubes with SSAS. I understand the various types of OLAP options ROLAP, HOLAP and MOLAP. However, when creating a data cube using SSAS (at least for 2008 version) I do not see where we choose this option. Would it be during the install of the server?

Where is the data stored when a data cube is created?

Comment: "I do not see where we choose this option." which option? The storage mode or the directory path?

Comment: @MartinSmith The storage mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dimensions in Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services [support either ROLAP or MOLAP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174909(v=sql.105).aspx).

Open the dimension in BIDS 2008, select the root dimension node

[image]

and change this in the properties window.

[image]

For fact data you open the cube and can similarly set the storage mode by selecting a measure group and altering the storage mode to one of HOLAP/ROLAP/MOLAP in its properties window.

[image]

But this only sets the default for new partitions. You still need to go onto the partitions tab of the cube designer and set any existing partitions to the desired configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is where OLAP puts everything by default, but during the install I believe you can choose where you want your olap database (Data Directories tab). Look for a .db folder for your olap database in the below location, as well as supporting files (like .xml) in the OLAP folder for your olap database.

...\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\

Comment: Is it a ROLAP, HOLAP or a MOLAP at this point? Is there a way to choose? Thanks